# SQLLite Error - Failed to open DB

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have the following sqllite code:

```
func createAndCheckDatabase()-> Bool
{
    var success: Bool = true

    var db:COpaquePointer = nil        // Get path to DB in Documents directory
    let docDir:AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    let path = docDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyDatabase.db")
    // Check if copy of DB is there in Documents directory
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !(fm.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {
        // The database does not exist, so copy to Documents directory
        let from = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent(databaseName)
        var error:NSError?
        if !fm.copyItemAtPath(from, toPath: path, error: &error) {
            //ALWAYS ERRORS HERE THE FIRST TIME
            println("SQLiteDB - #1 failed to open DB.")
            println("Error - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    databasePath = path
    // Open the DB
    let cpath = (path as NSString).UTF8String
    let error = sqlite3_open(cpath, &db)
    if error != SQLITE_OK {
        // Open failed, close DB and fail
        println("SQLiteDB - another error - couldn't open DB")
        sqlite3_close(db)
    }

    return success
}
```

I call this function within my app delegate with the thought that it would successfully create my database once (and only once). Whenever I clear settings and run it, it always hits the area I've marked (error) once. After running it again I never get this error anymore.

Is there some logic flaw in this code (I mostly copied this code) or am I perhaps reporting an error that is actually not? I suspect that it might just be happening the first time it creates, but i'm actually OK and can start interacting with the database just fine.

Also does anyone sees something concerning in the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after not really figuring out why the above code cobbled together from online tutorials did as I described, I found a very helpful article here:

```
 http://metrozines.com
```

This ended up solving my problem (by following how they did things and introducing the code from the tutorial). Now when I clear settings, it doesn't crash and starting it up again works correctly without throwing an error.

The code that works now is this:

```
func createAndCheckDatabase() -> Bool {
    let DATABASE_RESOURCE_NAME = "abc"
    let DATABASE_RESOURCE_TYPE = "sqlite"
    let DATABASE_FILE_NAME = "abc.sqlite"
    let documentFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let dbfile = "/" + DATABASE_FILE_NAME;

    self.dbFilePath = documentFolderPath.stringByAppendingString(dbfile)

    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if (!filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(dbFilePath) ) {

        let backupDbPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(DATABASE_RESOURCE_NAME, ofType: DATABASE_RESOURCE_TYPE)

        if (backupDbPath == nil) {
            return false
        } else {
            var error: NSError?
            let copySuccessful = filemanager.copyItemAtPath(backupDbPath!, toPath:dbFilePath, error: &error)
            if !copySuccessful {
                println("copy failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return false
            }

        }

    }

    return true

}
```

Comment: This isn't an actual answer. It would be much more helpful if you actually posted the code fix instead of a link.